# Printing a image in the mini thermal receipt printer adafruit using raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, terminal, printing

I have opened the command prompt on a Raspberry Pi and typed the command as:

```
lp -d ZJ-58 -o fit-to-page /home/pi/Documents/image_name.bmp
```

which produces the gibberish printing as follows:

[image: Image_Printer_Output]

Could anybody tell me, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: is the printer capable of printing graphics? ... if not, google `ASCII art`

Comment: yes, its working well beforehand and now the thermal printer is not printing for image

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say this, but considering the quality of the printing in your photo, I wouldn't expect this printer to ever produce a picture of decent quality.

More to the point, I would use `lpadmin` and `lpstat` commands to see if (a) the printer's URI corresponds to the expected configuration (like matching baudrate if this is set by the URI) and that a compatible driver is used (that is, if your device is really a ZJ-58, and the driver that is used is also set to ZJ-58).

I also see "CircuitPythonAMSIndia" repeated several times in the printout. Are you sure the printer is actually trying to print the picture, and not something else? Check out the printing queue (`lpq`): it may so happen that there is zero connection between this printout (resulting form your earlier experiments) and the picture (which sits in the printing queue and is not getting printed at all).

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed a printer „driver“ (CUPS filter)? I am using  [klirichek/zj-58](https://github.com/klirichek/zj-58) with great success.